# Internal scripts and style-sheets always points to index file (Node.JS)

Tags: linux, node.js, directory, handle

This is really weird problem. I just installed Node.JS on my system (Fedora).

I have three files in **/var/www/mirror/**:

- server.js
- client.js
- index.html

File **server.js** is the one I call via CLI: `node server.js`.

It, basically, returns **index.html**.

```
var
    http = require('http'),
    io   = require('socket.io'),
    fs   = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function(error, data) {

        if (error) {

            result.writeHead(500);

            console.log('Error: Could not read index.html.');

        }

        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end(data);

    });

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server is running.');
```

All works as expected and no errors are thrown anywhere.

In **index.html** I have simple HTML5 structure (nothing unnecessary, really!) and `<script />` that points to, already mentioned, **client.js**.

That line of code looks like this (Ctrl + U; from browser):

`<script src="client.js"></script>`

By moving cursor on `client.js`, I got actual location: `http://127.0.0.1:1337/client.js`.

Seems correct, right?

## The problem:

By opening that link it opens wanted file, but the content is as `server.js` should return.

This disallows me from including any internal scripts and style-sheets!

I guess that anything that goes via `http://127.0.0.1:1337/` (also `http://127.0.0.1:1337/client.js`, `http://127.0.0.1:1337/a/b/c` etc.) is handled via **server.js** - and **server.js** returns **index.html** (see above).

How can I fix it? Thanks in any advice!

Comment: Nothing weird here. `fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', ...` is in the code. It just does what you want it to do - to serve index.html to any request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `req.url` to tell you the url that the user is requesting.  From there, you have to have some code decide whether to serve index.html or client.js.

Also, since I'm guessing `index.html` isn't changing very frequently, you should probably just read it once, and store the buffer in a variable, rather than reading it on every request.

There are some modules that make serving static files a bit easier.  Check out `filed` for a pretty nice standalone static file

Comment: [This](http://www.thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/5/6/serving-static-files-from-node-js) made your answer even clearer. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. **Warning**: Read comments of that article (see above)!